# Types for return values from Apollo client

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

This is a standard query made with [`react-apollo`](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo):

```
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery<RocketInventoryData, RocketInventoryVars>(
  GET_ROCKET_INVENTORY,
  { variables: { year: 2019 } }
);
```

If I want pass `loading`, `data` or `error` to sub-components, is there any way to access the types for those from `react-apollo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already providing the type for `data` and `loading` is just a boolean. You can look at the type definition for the hook in your editor to determine what other types you might need.

```
export declare function useQuery<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>(query: DocumentNode, options?: QueryHookOptions<TData, TVariables>): QueryResult<TData, TVariables>;

export interface QueryResult<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>
  extends ObservableQueryFields<TData, TVariables> {
  client: ApolloClient<any>;
  data: TData | undefined;
  error?: ApolloError;
  loading: boolean;
  networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
}
```